# Invalid Floating Point Operation?

Tags: pascal

I am a beginner in Pascal. I made this simple calculating program and keep getting exitcode : 207 message when running this code. Some website says that it is because of the invalid floating point operation. So I suppose its because of the division of zero. But I don't know how to avoid that.

```pascal
uses crt;
var
    a, b, c, d, e, f : real;

begin
    c := a + b;
    d := a - b;
    e := a * b;
    f := a / b;
    writeln(' Basic Math Operation ');
    writeln('Write First Number a ');
    readln(a);
    writeln('Write Second Number b ');
    readln(b);
    writeln('The addition of a + b =', c);
    writeln('The substraction of a - b =', d);
    writeln('The multiplication of a x b =', e);
    writeln('The division of a / b =', f);
    readln;
end.
```

I also tried to add this but keep getting the same exitcode : 207

```pascal
if (b=0) then
   writeln(' Can't do division by 0 !')
else
   writeln('The division of a / b =', f);
```

or this one that i found on a forum

```
except on EDivByZero do ShowMessage('Can't do division by 0 !');
```

What shall i do???

Comment: The problem is the first four lines after `begin`. You perform calculations on zero-initialized global variables `a` and `b`. Don't perform the calculations before you have received users entries. Then use the `if ... else ...` code block in conjunction with calculating `f`.

Comment: Simple variables like these in Pascal are not necessarily initialized after declaration at all. They might be zero, but they might be rubbish. Best bet is to initialize variables before use.

Comment: @ChrisDutton Global variables are initialized to zero at program start. Local variables are not (except managed types) - I just saw that it is mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using [Free Pascal](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse24.html):

> By default, simple variables in Pascal are not initialized after their declaration. Any assumption that they contain 0 or any other default value is erroneous: They can contain rubbish. To remedy this, the concept of initialized variables exists. The difference with normal variables is that their declaration includes an initial value, as can be seen in the diagram in the previous section.
> Remark 2 exceptions to this rule exist:
>
> 1. Managed types are an exception to this rule: Managed types are always initialized with a default value: in general this means setting the reference count to zero, or setting the pointer value of the type to Nil. See section 3.9, page 226
> 2. **Global variables are initialized with the equivalent of zero.**

`a, b, c, d` are initialised to 0 at the start of the program. Therefore `f:=a/b` produces division by zero error. You should move the line `readln(a)` and `readln(b)` at the start of the program to assign a value to the variables before use. Also check whether `b` is inputted as 0 to avoid similar issues.